# LED controlled by MOSFET is always on

Tags: mosfet, pwm, raspberry-pi

In my circuit I am attempting to control a LED's brightness via a PWM signal applied to a MOSFET (which then provides power to the LED). This is shown in the image below; power comes in via USB(orange), is boosted to 12V(green), and then sent to the MOSFET circuit(magenta), where the connector is for the LED.

All of this is on a shield for a RPI Zero where the "LED_PWM" pin is connected to the RPI.

The problem is that as soon as USB power is connected, the LED powers on, regardless as to whether the shield is connected to the RPI (meaning LED_PWM is connected to the RPI) or not.

Is this simply leakage current through the MOSFET? I would have expected that since the PWM output of the RPI pin is disabled

[image]

Comment: What voltage do you measure between G and S? Btw, when you drive mosfet with PWM always use some resistance to Gate. At least 22ohm.

Comment: Q1 in the schematic is not a MOSFET.  If it is a MOSFET then check to see if D & S are reversed.  Is it a N or P type.  Part number please?

Comment: What is the Led rating (Vf, If)? BS170 at 3v3 can drive 50-100mA maximum. Maybe BJT would be a better solution because it can be controlled with smaller voltage.

Comment: Since you're already using the wrong symbol for your "MOSFET" (you're using an NPN BJT instead), my bet is that you have the pinout wrong on your actual part and as romsimpson wrote above, you've probably got D and S reversed.

Comment: If that transistor were a 2N2222, then pin 1 would be the one you connect to ground and pin 3 would connect to the cathode of the LED.  For the BS170, pin 3 is connected to ground and pin 1 is connected to the cathode of the LED.  Like the others have said, you probably have it backwards and are seeing continuous conduction through the body diode of the MOSFET.

Comment: @ronsimpson I am using a BS170. which is listed as N-channel enhancement mode. https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mmbf170-d.pdf

Comment: @brhans It seems that I do have the wrong symbol, and yes it does look like I have it the wrong way around.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický The BS170 can drive maximum 500mA, and the LED only draws something like 10mA given the resistor in series, so it is a bit overdimensioned. Would it still be better to use a BJT?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I will look into resistance to gate

Comment: @vir Yes, I think you guys are right about that, will resolder it.